# TypeError: Invalid foreground RGBA argument

Tags: python, pygame

Every time I try to run the Pygame program, I get this error:

> TypeError: Invalid foreground RGBA argument

Here is my code, do you have any idea why ?

```py
text = font.render(b’Score:’ , dude.score, 1, (0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: I'm not sure it'll fix it, but ```(0,0,0)``` is RGB, ```(0,0,0,1)``` is RGBA.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi It didn’t. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 6):

as per [the docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) Font.render takes rgb as his third argument, you pass it as fourth.
This does not raise a proper error because `font.render` takes a fourth optional argument background.

Try `text = font.render('Score:'+str(dude.score), 1, (0, 0, 0))`

Answer (score 0):

The first 3 parameters of [`pygame.font.Font.render`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) are position-only parameters. Positional-Only Parameters. The *text*, *antialiasing* and the *color*. Therefore, you can just pass a single string to the rendering function.

Use a [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

```py
text = font.render(f'Score: {dude.score}', 1, (0, 0, 0))
```

or use the ['str()'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) function to convert the number to a string and concatenate the strings

```py
text = font.render('Score: ' + str(dude.score), 1, (0, 0, 0))
```